# How to download Tags / keyword tags from a Site collections - SP 2010

Tags: 2010, managed-metadata, tagging

I have a scenario, we have a web application where multiple site collections are hosted.
among which there are 3 site collections... sub sites within each site collection which are critical for users to upload docs in libraries. Like wise users are uploading docs in other site collection libraries as well.

now each user is tagging the documents from different site collections as per their convenience. May be there are multiple users tagging the same document. 
we have a issue like since many users have started tagging their documents, it is utilizing lot of storage and in near future the utilize all the resource.

So, my question is, is there a way to retrieve or download the 'system tags' according to the site collections / documents and also which user has tagged which document? so that we can delete all the unnecessary tags from non-critical site collections.

Answer (score 0):

ootb:

goto central admin -> application management -> under service application click on Manage service applications -> click on User Profile Service Application -> under My Site Settings 
click on Manage Social Tags and Notes -> when the new page loads just add the url for the site you want to search and hit find.

you can be more specific if looking for a specific tag or a user tags only but either case it needs the url for the site your searching against!

[image]

anything more complex will require a custom solution like creating an application.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/programmatically-get-all-the-social-tags-for-the-specified-url-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Hi Ali, Thanks for your answer. I knew the Manage Social Tags and Notes setting. However, in my case there are 100s of users, checking tags for each user is a cumbersome job. I will check the code. Thanks!

Comment: it doesnt need to be for user specific, you could search on the tag. Are you rather looking to seach on the document instead?

Comment: Im looking to search the tags on all the docs / lists / folders / pages on a particular site collection. so that all the unwanted tags can be deleted from the 'System' term set from term store.